# Access shared preference in react native

Tags: android, react-native, android-sharedpreferences

Is it possible to access shared preference of Android in react native?For Example if I create one

`SharedPreferences sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences("somePreference", Context.MODE_ENABLE_WRITE_AHEAD_LOGGING);`

How can the keys then be accessed in react native?

Comment: @Mandy8055 What does it mean?Mind elaborating ?

Answer (score 3):

You can do something like this:

In your Handler class you can create a constructor and an init method to get this context to the ReactNatives's Application context.

```
private static Handler handler;
public Handler(Context context) {
SharedPreferences sharedpreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(SHARED_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
}
public static void init(Context context) {
    handler = new Handler(context);
}
//Getting keys to the React native
 public Map<String, ?> getAllSharedData(){
    return sharedpreferences.getAll();
}
```

In your class which is providing data(ProvideData) you can do something

```
public static String[] getAllKeys() {
    Map<String, ?> keyValues = Handler.getInstance().getAllSharedData();
    List<String> keys = new ArrayList<>(keyValues.keySet());
    String[] results = new String[keys.size()];
    for (int i = 0; i < keys.size(); i++) {
        results[i] = keys.get(i);
    }
    return results;
}
```

and finally get your keys in the RNSharedPreference(**getReactApplicationContext()**)

```
@ReactMethod
public void getAllKeys(Callback successCallback){
    Handler.init(getReactApplicationContext());
    String[] keys = ProvideData.getAllKeys();
    WritableNativeArray data = new WritableNativeArray();
    for(int i=0; i<keys.length; i++){
        data.pushString(keys[i]);
    }
    successCallback.invoke(data);
}
```

Comment: similar solution: https://github.com/sriraman/react-native-shared-preferences